# connection not opening from WCF with dsn

Tags: c#, wcf, oledb, oledbconnection, dsn

This code is written in WCF. when I add reference from localhost then this code works fine but when service reference is added from IIS then it fails in cn.Open() . It doesn't throw any exception and just hangs in this line.

```
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=myDsn;Uid=myuid;Pwd=mypassword;";
        cn.Open(); // Fails on this line
```

Or is there any other way which which I can get datasource name with dsn in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Makes sure the DSN was created as a system DSN and not a user DSN.  If it's created as a user DSN (as you) then the IIS service user will not have access to it.

Comment: When you created the DSN did you select "With Windows NT authentication using network login ID" or "With SQL Server authentication using a login ID and password entered by the user"?

Comment: Which driver did you use when you created the DSN?

Comment: Not windows authentication, its SQL server authentication ...SQL Native client..yes if i use direct connection string it works . It even works from console but not from WCF

Comment: Console and WCF run under different user contexts.  Using a connection string instead of the DSN suggest there's some permissions thing t hat is keep the WCF user context from accessing the DSN.  Without more detail, it's impossible to tell.  Why is a connection string not sufficient?